# gatsby-image: difference between childImageSharp vs imageSharp

Tags: gatsby

I'm using gatsby-image to handle automatically handle different image sizes. It works great.

However, in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/) of gatsby-image, one example uses `imageSharp` in graphql to get different image sizes, while another example uses `childImageSharp`. I was curious what the difference between the two are?

I assume it has to do with either `gatsby-transformer-sharp` or `gatsby-plugin-sharp`, but the docs for those plugins don't have any info on that either.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I hope to give a direct answer to the question 'what's the different between imageSharp and childImageSharp':

### Different between `imageSharp` & `childImageSharp`

They are always the same type of node, which is `ImageSharp`. The difference is the reference point.

In a typical gatsby blog, all files will be first processed with `gatsby-transformer-file-system`. Each file will get a node with information such as what type of file it is, then, a plugin like `gatsby-transformer-sharp` will pick up the node with the relevant type/extension, then process it further and create a new node:

```
File                                image.png

                                        |

                                   create a node with
gatsby-transformer-file-system ->  "type": "File",
                                   "extension": "png"

                                        |

                                   whenever see a node 
                                   with a valid image extension,
gatsby-transformer-sharp       ->  create a node with
                                   "type": "ImageSharp"
                                   that contains info of images
                                   processed by `gatsby-plugin-sharp`
```

Whenever this happens, a parent-child relationship is created between the original `File` node and the `ImageSharp` node. The child `ImageSharp` node will be queriable on the `File` node with the name `childImageSharp`.

```
File                                ImageSharp
  |--id: 1                              |--id: 2
  |--children                           |--parent
  |     `--[ id: 2 ]                    |    `--id: 1
  `--childImageSharp                    |--fluid
        |--id: 2                       ...
        |--fluid
       ...
```

It means you can query the same `ImageSharp` node in at least 2 ways:

#### 1. From the File node

`ImageSharp` node doesn't contain any info about its location in the file system, so if you want to get an image from folder `src/X`, you'd need to query it like:

```
query {
  // relativePath is relative to the folder set in `gatsby-transformer-file-system`
  file ( relativePath: { eq: "src/X"} ) {
    childImageSharp {
      id
      fluid {
        src
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### 2.Directly get the `ImageSharp`

Perhaps somehow you know the exact `id` of the ImageSharp node. You can get it by:

```
{
  imageSharp (id: {eq: "2"}) { // not a real id
    id
    fluid {
      src
    }
  }
}
```

You can also query multiple images from `allFile`, or `allImageSharp`.

This will return with an error:

```
// error
{
  childImageSharp {
    id
  }
}
```

Other plugins share the same kind of relationship as well. You can also find a `childMardownRemark` node on the `File` type, that resolve to a `MarkdownRemark` node.

It doesn't have anything to do with `gatsby-image` -- it's just different way to resolve to the same node.

Answer (score 4):

Great question, Sharp is an amazing tool and can do so much with any JavaScript application. It also has extensive documentation its self I suggested looking in to.http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/

First imageSharp can be used in a variety of ways especially with the Transform. But here is an simple example of just utilizing imageSharp in the Gatsby universe. Imagine this is `index.js` in the pages `folder` and there is  route of `home`

```
import { Home } from 'routes/Home/Home'

/* eslint no-undef: "off" */
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query HomeQuery {
    image1Image: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/image1.png/" }) {
      sizes(quality: 100) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_withWebp
      }
    }
    image2Image: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/image2.png/" }) {
      sizes(quality: 100) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_withWebp
      }
    }
    image3Image: imageSharp(id: { regex: "/image3.png/" }) {
      sizes(quality: 100) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_withWebp
      }
    }
}
`
export default Home
```

Then a `childImageSharp` you would use this for defining image styles throughout an application, for instance you have a folder called `types` the path would be `src/types/images.js` for example in this file you would define the resolution and size of the image and the datasets associated. Then export `childImageSharp` as you plan to reuse the child over and over in different parts of your app.

```
// @flow

export type GatsbyImageResolutions = {
    resolutions: {
        base64?: string,
        height: number,
        src: string,
        srcSet: string,
        width: number,
    },
};

export type GatsbyImageSizes = {
    sizes: {
        aspectRatio: number,
        base64?: string,
        sizes: string,
        src: string,
        srcSet: string,
    },
};

export type Image = {
    childImageSharp: GatsbyImageResolutions | GatsbyImageSizes,
};
```

Now here is an example of the power of transforming an image. This example is a  returned with a ImageURL via the WordPress REST-api to a standard href=link to a link. Well Resizing and reshaping the image with childIamgeSharp! Both existing in one file `src/post/post.js`

```
/**
     * Transform internal absolute link to relative.
     * 
     * @param {string} string The HTML to run link replacemnt on
     */
    linkReplace(string) {
        // console.log(string)
        const formatted = string.replace(
            /(href="https?:\/\/dev-your-image-api\.pantheonsite\.io\/)/g,
            `href="/`
        )

        return formatted
    }

    render() {
        const post = { ...this.props.data.wordpressPost }
        const headshot = { ...this.props.data.file.childImageSharp.resolutions }
        const { percentScrolled } = { ...this.state }
        const contentFormatted = this.linkReplace(post.content)

        return (
            <div ref={el => (this.post = el)}>
                <div className={styles.progressBarWrapper}>
                    <div
                        style={{ width: `${percentScrolled}%` }}
                        className={styles.progressBar}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className={styles.post}>
                    <h1
                        className={styles.title}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.title }}
                    />

                    <div
                        className={styles.content}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: contentFormatted }}
                    />

                    <Bio headshot={headshot} horizontal={true} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Post.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default Post

export const postQuery = graphql`
    query currentPostQuery($id: String!) {
        wordpressPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
            wordpress_id
            title
            content
            slug
        }
        file(relativePath: { eq: "your-image-headshot.jpg" }) {
            childImageSharp {
                resolutions(width: 300, height: 300) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpResolutions
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you,If not I would be glad to help explain in more detail. As Sharp and Gatsby are both subjects I am very Passionate about and I deal with Sharp almost daily in my full-time Job.

Comment: hey thanks for the detailed response. I'm actually still having a bit of trouble following you. From your example, it looks like `childImageSharp` isn't even part of the gatsby-image library? It's just an arbitrary user-defined type? So in theory, we could name `childImageSharp` anything we want. However, since `imageSharp` is part of gatsby-image, we cannot name `imageSharp` anything we want?

Comment: The documentation link you provided (http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/) doesn't work anymore as of August 2019

Comment: @nick-c I tried using `imageSharp` directly as you suggested, but it was never able to find the image I referenced.  Does that image need to be in a specific folder?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay in response & maybe you have a better understanding now but figured I would follow up here.

Referring back to Gatsby 1.0 as when I answered this question 2.0 was not released yet. But a few things have to be taken in to account 1 where is the image path? and 2 is the image coming from an MD file for a blog post or a assets file or API?

This is what a component using gatsby-image looks like: *(this is from the Gatsby v1 Docs)*

```
import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello gatsby-image</h1>
    <Img fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />
  </div>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "blog/avatars/kyle-mathews.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        # Specify the image processing specifications right in the query.
        # Makes it trivial to update as your page's design changes.
        fixed(width: 125, height: 125) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Gatsby-image directly uses components from the [Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) library. As you see above gatsby-image uses childImageSharp referencing the GraphQL query where you define the file path, size, etc of the image. It would be considered a child because the original or "origin" image in the filesystem is a different makeup in size or file type.

ImageSharp can be used when defining the node or a general sense of the image in a component or layout as no specific path for an image is being called directly.