# Gatsby getting image path after graphql query has returned

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

So I've written a blog site in Gatsby and Remark. I've structured my posts like this:

```
Library/
 -- category-name/
 ---- article-name/
 ------ index.md
```

This has worked really well and results in me being able to make paths like `/category-name/article-name`.

What I also would like to do is to be able to drop an image in there called 'hero.jpg' and for it to be automatically picked up by Gatsby without having to add a frontmatter reference to it.

I've managed to get so far by adding the following to 'gatsby-node.js':

```js
const hero = (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `src/library/pages/${slug}hero.jpg`))) ? `${slug}hero.jpg` : ''
createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'hero',
      value: hero,
    })
```

This works as far as the graphql data goes and I now see the following:

```
{
  "node": {
  "id": "3190922a-2207-5621-a7be-e02be9e8da24",
  "fields": {
    "hero": "/category-name/article-name/hero.jpg"
  },
},
```

However on the actual page, the image link `/category-name/article-name/hero.jpg` doesn't exist so I get a dead image. I know this is because my image path is being transformed by `gatsby-transformer-sharp` but I don't know how to work out what it is being transformed to.

I believe I need to do something akin to the answers on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141031/gatsby-image-difference-between-childimagesharp-vs-imagesharp) but that seems to expect you to know that the `relativePath` is at the time you are writing your query but I won't have that information until after the query has returned the first time.

**OnCreateNode hook added for claarity**

```js
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  // Add slug to MarkdownRemark node
  if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: 'library' })
    const hero = (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, `src/library/pages/${slug}hero.jpg`))) ? './hero.jpg' : ''

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'slug',
      value: slug,
    })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'hero',
      value: hero,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? In your `gatsby-config.js`, how is `gatsby-source-filesystem` being set up with images? How are you loading the `hero` url into your blog template? In `gatsby-node.js` I assume you're adding node in the `onCreateNode` hook, could you share the whole hook?

Comment: Sure thing, so gatsby-source-filesystem is looking in `./src/images` which is fine for general site images but for blog images I want them to all be stored in the same folder as the markdown so yes, I added a new node, the hook is now an edit on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized my previous answer was incorrect & overly complicated (It relies on node creation order, also there's no need to add fields to imageSharp nodes. Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54283782/1) if someone's interested.). Here's the better answer:

### Querying image of `hero` name in the same folder with mardown

Since the hero image is always at the same directory as the markdown file, we can simply query it based on its directory.

```
            dir              name  ext
┌────────────┴────────────┐ ┌─┴─┐ ┌─┴─┐
absolute/path/to/directory/ hero  .png
absolute/path/to/directory/ index .md
```

Graphql query:

```
file ( dir: { eq: "absolute/path/to/directory" }, name: { "hero" } ) {
  childImageSharp {
    fixed {
      src
    }
  }
}
```

The only modification you need to make to your `gatsby-node.js` is to add this `dir` field to your page's `context` so we can use it as a variable.
We can get this `dir` by doing `path.parse(node.fileAbsolutePath).dir`, or get the `dir` field from remark's parent node `getNode(node.parent.id).dir`

```
   +  const { dir } = getNode(node.parent.id)

      createPage({
        path: node.fields.slug,
        component,
        context: {
   +      dir,
          slug: node.fields.slug,
        },
      })
```

And query it like so:

```
    export const pageQuery = graphql`
   -  query ArticleByPath($slug: String!) {
   +  query ArticleByPath($slug: String!, $dir: String!) {
        markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
          id
          htmlAst
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
   +    file (dir: { eq: $dir }, name: { eq: "hero" }) {
   +      childImageSharp {
   +        fixed {
   +          src
   +        }
   +      }
   +    }
      }
    `
```

And use it:

```
    export default function Template({ data }) {
      const post = data.markdownRemark
  +   const hero = data.file ? data.file.childImageSharp : null
      return (
        <div className="landing-page-container">
          <Helmet title={`Your Blog Name - ${post.frontmatter.title}`} />
          <div className="blog-post">
  +         {hero && <img src={hero.fixed.src} alt={post.frontmatter.title} />}
            <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <div className="blog-post-content">{renderAst(post.htmlAst)}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Here's [the gist for `article.js` and `gatsby-node.js`.](https://gist.github.com/d4rekanguok/e2a67760db7fcd6452538e85d7378120)

Comment: No problems, I was doing something sort of similar and thought it’d be fun to try to get this done. Our setup might differ though, so let me know how it goes on your end

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help, finally got time to do it and it sort of works. Interestingly though it only works for .png images and completely ignores the .jpg files (not got gifs so not sure if it works with those).

If you're interested in seeing what I've done, you can see it here:
https://github.com/foxleigh81/blog.foxleigh.me/blob/master/gatsby-node.js

Comment: I actually lead you down the (incorrect and) overly-complicated path, sorry about that! Will update the answer in a bit

Comment: So an interesting thing I discovered today: You can't put variables in a component graphql query as it seems to require the use of StaticQuery. Which means I can't see a way of getting the hero image on a list page as there is no obvious way to pass the $dir value to `allMarkdownRemark`. We might have to use the frontmatter after all :-/

Comment: @AlexFoxleigh ah I guess we have to link the nodes after all. I gotta say, this is a lot harder than it should be!

Comment: Agreed. I'm surprised at how difficult this is proving to be. I've tried this but to no avail, not sure if I'm going the right direction here though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636627/add-childimagesharp-to-a-field-not-frontmatter