# Add ImageSharp as a field to MarkdownRemark nodes (not frontmatter)

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have the following graphQL query I'm trying to get working:

```
 {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            parent {
              id
            }
            fields{
              slug
              hero {
                childImageSharp {
                  fixed {
                    src
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            frontmatter {
              template
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The `hero` field currently returns a path to an image using the following code:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  // Add slug to MarkdownRemark node
  if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: 'library' })
    const { dir } = getNode(node.parent)
    const getHero = (d) => {
      let hero = `${__dirname}/src/images/no-hero.gif`
      if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.jpg`)) hero = `${d}/hero.jpg`
      if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.png`)) hero = `${d}/hero.png`
      if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.gif`)) hero = `${d}/hero.gif`
      return hero
    }
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'slug',
      value,
    })

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'hero',
      value: getHero(dir),
    })
  }
}
```

I've seen other people do something similar with an image path in the `frontmatter` but I don't want to have to use the frontmatter when it's easy enough to get graphql to see the file path without having to specify it.

However when I try the above I get the following error:

> Field \"hero\" must not have a selection since type \"String\" has no
>   subfields.

Is there a way I can get `childImageSharp` to recognize this field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm back again to (hopefully) settle this issue once and for all (see our history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205509/gatsby-getting-image-path-after-graphql-query-has-returned)).

This time, we'll attach the hero image's `ImageSharp` to the `MarkdownRemark` node. Your approach is **correct**, with 1 caveat: Gatsby seems to only recognize relative paths, i.e path starting with a dot.

You can fix this easily in your code:

```
    const getHero = (d) => {
      let hero = `${__dirname}/src/images/no-hero.gif`

  -   if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.jpg`)) hero = `${d}/hero.jpg`
  -   if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.png`)) hero = `${d}/hero.png`
  -   if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.gif`)) hero = `${d}/hero.gif`

  +   if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.jpg`)) hero = `./hero.jpg`
  +   if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.png`)) hero = `./hero.png`
  +   if (fs.existsSync(`${d}/hero.gif`)) hero = `./hero.gif`

      return hero
    }
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'hero',
      value: getHero(dir),
    })
```

This should work, though I want to provide an alternative hero search function. We can get a list of files in `dir` with `fs.readdir`, then find a file with the name 'hero':

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node, actions,
}) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    const { dir } = path.parse(node.fileAbsolutePath)

    const heroImage = await new Promise((res, rej) => {

      // get a list of files in `dir`
      fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) rej(err)

        // if there's a file named `hero`, return it
        res(files.find(file => file.includes('hero')))
      })
    })

    // path.relative will return a (surprise!) a relative path from arg 1 to arg 2.
    // you can use this to set up your default hero
    const heroPath = heroImage 
      ? `./${heroImage}` 
      : path.relative(dir, 'src/images/default-hero.jpg')

    // create a node with relative path
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'hero',
      value: `./${heroImage}`,
    })
  }
}
```

This way we don't care what the hero image's extension is, as long as it exists. I use `String.prototype.includes`, but you might want to use regex to pass in a list of allowed extensions, to be safe, like `/hero.(png|jpg|gif|svg)/`. (I think your solution is more readable, but I prefer to access the file system only once per node.)

You can also use [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) to find the relative path to a default hero image.

Now, this graphql query works:

[image]

---

## A (Minor) Problem

However, there's a minor problem with this approach: it breaks graphql filter type! When I try to query and filter based on `hero`, I get this error:

[image]

Perhaps Gatsby forgot to re-infer the type of `hero`, so instead of being a `File`, it is still a `String`. This is annoying if you need the filter to work.

Here's a workaround: Instead of asking Gatsby to link the file, we'll do it ourselves.

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node, actions, getNode, getNodesByType,
}) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  // Add slug to MarkdownRemark node
  if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    const { dir } = path.parse(node.fileAbsolutePath)
    const heroImage = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) rej(err)
        res(files.find(file => file.includes('hero')))
      })
    })

    // substitute with a default image if there's no hero image
    const heroPath = heroImage ? path.join(dir, heroImage) : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images/default-hero.jpg')

    // get all file nodes
    const fileNodes = getNodesByType('File')

    // find the hero image's node
    const heroNode = fileNodes.find(fileNode => fileNode.absolutePath === heroPath)
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'hero___NODE',
      value: heroNode.id,
    })
  }
}
```

And now we can filter the `hero` field again:
[image]

If you don't need to filter content by hero image though, letting gatsby handle node type is much preferable.

Let me know if you run into issues trying this.

Comment: I can't believe we finally nailed it! I went with the middle solution as it's cleaner and I don't need filtering :)