# What's the canonical way to attach an image to a node with Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I'm currently `onCreateNode` in `gatsby-node.js` to modify some nodes after they've been created. One thing I want to do is attach an image (or perhaps another type of file) to the node. Let's say the image exists elsewhere on the filesystem and I can get its absolute path by calling an (async) function called `getImageForNode(node)`, how can I then attach this to my node so that:

1. It's moved into `/static/` during build, so that it can be served by the website.
2. It's recognised as being an image so I can access its width/height/url and any other metadata I may need (I don't need to resize it, but I don't mind if that' made possible too).

`gatsby-source-filesystem` has a `createRemoteFileNode` function, but it only works with images that are served over the internet (and I don't really want to be setting up a local http server just for this, and it doesn't seem to support `file://`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatsby comes with a few plugins that'll help you:

`gatsby-source-filesystem` will pull file data into your gatsby app,
`gatsby-transformer-sharp` will ask `gatsby-plugin-sharp` to process your images & copy them to the public folder.

You can ask gatsby to link a file to another node for you by adding a relative path as a field in that node. You could also link it manually.

### Set up

You need to let gatsby know where your files are located:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: absolute/path/to/a/directory,
    name: `anything`,
  },
},
```

It can find directory outside of your root directory as well.

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../images')
```

### Adding a relative path to existing node

Say you have a `Json` node, created by `gatsby-transformer-remark` or other gatsby's official plugins, you can add a new field to it:

```
    const fileAbsolutePath = /* find this node's absolute path */
    const imageAboslutePath = /* do your get absolute path thing */
    const imageRelativePath = path.relative(fileAbsolutePath, imageAboslutePath)

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `image`,
      value: imageRelativePath,
    })
```

This will link the new field `image` to a File node, where you can find a `imageSharp` node with image information.

Then you can query it like

```
query {
  markdownRemark {
    fields {               <-- fields created by `createNodeField` will live here
      image {              <-- point to a file node
        childImageSharp {  <-- point to imageSharp node of this file
          fixed {
            width          <-- see more info in gatsby-plugin-sharp documentation
            height
            srcSet
            src
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Link node manually

If the node you're modifying doesn't have a file, then you'd have to link it manually. `createNodeField` can still be used, but you'd have to pass in the target node's id instead. This is not yet documented.

```
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: 'target___NODE', <--- `___NODE` will resolve to another node
      value: targetNode.id,
    })
```

---

You can find code example with more detail in this [other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54654716/10340970).

Comment: Thanks Derek. Whilst not quite what i'm looking for, this is very thorough for people in a similar situation. In my case the files don't actually exist before I call `getImageForNode`, so the usual advice around configuring `gatsby-source-filesystem` doesn't work. I have it working now, so i'll write up what I did and update this.

Comment: Oh I missed that! I imagine the canonical way to deal with that is to call `getImageForNode` to pull files into a folder in prebootstrap step. Looking forward to seeing how you handle it!

Comment: @AndrewIngram It looks like you can fetch the images & add them to nodes in the `setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType` hook. I found a sophisticate example [in gatsby's contentful plugin](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/src/extend-node-type.js). Wonder if you did something similar, since this is probably as canonical as it get!

Comment: I ended up doing it this way: https://andrewingram.net/posts/automatic-social-cards-with-gatsby/

It feels a bit hacky though, I think using `setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType` is a bit more elegant because it means i can avoid the overhead of generating the image if the field isn't queried.

Comment: @AndrewIngram Nice job, this'd make a great plugin I think. Beautiful blog btw! Edit: Oh, there's already one. But it'd be cool to have something that accepts a design template.